# How do I call an ArrayAdapter function from my Utility class?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-adapter

Hi in my ArrayAdapter class when I click on button I'm showing Alert dialog box.

This alert dialog box and all related coding part is written in my "Common utility" class as like below.

My requirement is when I tap on alert dialogue box `OK` and `CANCEL` buttons  I want to handle that click events in my Adapter class

how can I do this please suggest me some one

### CommonUtilities:-

```
public class CommonUtils  {

   BackGroundDialogeCall backGroundDialogeCall;

   public interface BackGroundDialogeCall {

      void doDialogueExecute(String result);
   }
//Adding Dialoge box:-

/**
 *
 */

public void displaySignOutAlertDialog(Context activity) {

   new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
         .setTitle("Alert")
         .setMessage(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.release_alert_title))
         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                 int which) {

                     dialog.dismiss();
                  }
               })
         .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                 int which) {
                     dialog.dismiss();
                  }
               }).show();
   }
}
```

### Adapterclass:-

```
public class StockBookingExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements CommonUtils.BackGroundDialogeCall {

    private Context context;

    public StockBookingExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<StockBookingHeaderBean> stockbookingList) {

        this.context = context;
    }
@Override
public void doDialogueExecute(String result) {

    if (result.equals("yes")){
        Log.d("=====>", "111");
    }else{
        Log.d("=====>", "222");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a `CommonUtils.BackGroundDialogeCall` to `displaySignOutAlertDialog()` and call the `doDialogueExecute()` in there.

```
public void displaySignOutAlertDialog(Context activity,
                                final BackGroundDialogeCall call) {
    [...]
         .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                 int which) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
                 call.doDialogueExecute("yes");
              }
           })
    [...]
}
```

Now you could just call `displaySignOutAlertDialog()` with `StockBookingExpandableAdapter` as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void displaySignOutAlertDialog(Context activity, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okHandler, DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelHandler)
```

Add dialog button handler as your function's parameters. And you have not initialize handler on displaySignOutAlertDialog